# Vue.js Testing - Banner not showing after button click

Tags: typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue.js Component, that shows a BootstrapVue banner in response to a submit error. Everything works fine during manual testing, but the corresponding unit test fails.

The error is the following.

```
[vue-test-utils]: find did not return #submit-failure-banner, cannot call isVisible() on empty Wrapper

      36 | 
      37 |         const errorBanner = wrapper.find("#submit-failure-banner")
    > 38 |         expect(errorBanner.isVisible()).toBeTruthy()
         |                            ^
      39 |     })
      40 | })
      41 |
```

```js
it("shows an error message on post failure", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(NewSite, {
        localVue,
        provide: {
            sites: new Sites(internalServerErrorRequestHandler)
        }
    });
    const siteOwnerInput = wrapper.find('#new-site-owner-input');
    siteOwnerInput.setValue(owner);
    const saveButton = wrapper.find('#new-site-save');
    saveButton.trigger('click');
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    const errorBanner = wrapper.find("#submit-failure-banner")
    expect(errorBanner.isVisible()).toBeTruthy()
})
```

The Relevant parts of the `NewSite` component are the following, starting with the banner element in the template.

```
<b-alert id="submit-failure-banner" variant="danger" v-model="banners.submitFailure" dismissible>
    {{ $t('$MESSAGE_SITE_SAVE_FAILED') }}
</b-alert>
```

```js
export default class NewSite extends Vue {
    @Inject('sites') private sites!: Sites

    form = {
        owner: ''
    }
    banners = {
        submitFailure: false,
        ...
    }

    async postForm() {
        return await this.sites.create({
            owner: this.form.owner,
            state: SiteStatus.NEW
        }).save()
    }
   ...
   async onSave() {
        if (!this.checkForm()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            await this.postForm();
            await this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
        } catch (_) {
            this.banners.submitFailure = true;
        }
    }
```

The relevant part of the `Sites` class does nothing more than a POST request using a request handler. This is `axios` in production, and a mock request handler during tests. The `internalServerErrorRequestHandler` is defined like this.

```
const internalServerErrorRequestHandler = {
    post(url: string, data: any): Promise<Response> {
        return Promise.reject()
    }
}
```

I verified that the html doesn't show the banner, via a `console.log` statement.

Comment: I think you need to add an additional `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();` after triggering your click to allow time for Vue to process the click handler and the `<transition>` (which is the root of `<b-alert>`).

Comment: I tried adding an additional `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();` and also stubbing `transition` like it is described [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/common-tips.html#mocking-transitions). Neither fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually, you might need the mount option `attachToFocument: true`, and instead of `wrapper.find('#submit-failure-banner')` use `documentQuerySelector('#submit-failure-banner')`, and check that the element is div instead of isVisible.

Comment: or perhaps, after your await nextTick, add `await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve))`, which will allow time for the un-stubbed transition to trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I solved to Problem by stubbing the `BAlert` component, thereby removing the `transition` element. The stub I used is the following.

```
<template>
    <div :v-show="value" :id="id">
        <slot/>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Vue, Component, Prop} from "vue-property-decorator";

    @Component
    export default class BAlertStub extends Vue {
        @Prop() value = false
        @Prop() id = ""
    }
</script>
```